# Python CannotFindModule with importlib

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, python-importlib

I have a question about importing modules in python with the importlib library.

Here is the problem:
I have two `.py` files (`a.py` and `b.py`) in `/src`. The `b.py` file imports the `a.py` module, i.e. I have something like:

```
/src
       a.py
       b.py
```

In b.py:

```py
from a import *
# [some codes here]
```

When I import the b.py file with this code:

```py
module_name = extract_module_name(filename)
spec = iu.spec_from_file_location(name=module_name, location=filename)
imported_module = iu.module_from_spec(spec)
# The following line raise an exception ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
spec.loader.exec_module(imported_module)
```

The last line throws an exception that it cannot find module `a.py`

I don't know how the `loader.exec_module()` works, but normally it should import all modules declared in the `b.py` (Note: there is no problem with python libraries, it can import them).

My goal is to have something that can load the `b.py` module with all its declared modules to import.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `filename`? And what does `extract_module_name` look like (or rather, what is the value of `module_name`?

Comment: The value of the filename is the absolute path of the b.py (on Linux it's something like home/path/to/b.py) and the value of the module_name is just ''b''(the basename of the filename)

Comment: I think the underlying reason is simply that `a` is not on your PYTHONPATH, or on `sys.path`. It can probably import `b` because you more or less force-feed its location to Python, but it doesn't know where to look for `a`. I've tried your setup but with a relative import, `from .a import *`, and adding an `__init__.py` to `src/`, but that doesn't seem to work either. Probably because it doesn't recognize `src/` as a package (and thus `from .a import` as an internal relative import`, but only `b` as a standalone module.

Comment: With my above comment: is there a reason why you want to do things this somewhat convoluted way? Why not turn `src/` into a package and let Python do everything for you?

Comment: I am working on test framework and i need to import users files before running tests. But when a file imports another one it doesn't work with the above solution.